# Where to find google suite api key?

Tags: google-api, google-apis-explorer

I've just created a g suite free trial, and am trying to work with the Calendar API's. I've turned on "Enable API access" under API references from within the admin console.

I'm looking through [the api documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/) and am able to hit some example API calls using their in-browser "Try this API" function. Though, when I look at the HTML code, I'm given a URL that looks like this;

GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/resources/buildings?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Where do I find this API key? I can't find it in the admin console anywhere. Was this generated when I enabled API access? Is Google injecting it in when I hit the "Execute" button on "Try this API"? Also, where can I find my unique ID for my g suite account so I don't have to use "my_customer"?

Answer (score 1):

The API Key is one of the options that you have to generate OAuth credentials. To get an API key you need to create a project at https://console.developers.google.com/ 
- Once the Project is created get sure to select it from the upper left drop-down menu. 
- Go to "Library" from the left side and search for the API that you want to work with(Drive API, Admin SDK, Calendar API, etc.) and enable it. 
- You can now generate the API, from the left side menu go to "Credentials". Select "Create Credentials". The first option will be API key.